# Amazon API for pulling account for pulling sales information?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to help my wife setup her site to use an Amazon API for pulling sales related information (i.e. specific product sales, prices, etc.) The simplest way to explain: she's a middleman for Seller A and Seller B. Seller A sells Product X and Seller B sells Product Y.

I want to know which Amazon API can authenticate using the main account since both products are sold under that account, specify Product X and pulls sales related data and return the sales information. I will then present this information to Seller A. Then, I specify Product Y using the main account to authenticate and then display this return to Seller B.

Which API from Amazon will accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one. It's been asked for for years.

Comment: (Forgive me as I don't use Amazon myself so if this is a stupid question...) When you login to Amazon to look at your product sales, is there an actual breakdown on their site? Or they don't even provide this breakdown under your account at all?

Comment: There is a breakdown, and you can download it in CSV or "excel" format. But it's awful to read. If you're doing print books through Amazon (done via CreateSpace), it's similar--a breakdown, and you can run/save a report.